# How to trigger a script when I see that I get a SNMP Set packet

Tags: snmp, packet, capture

I have a something that is sending an SNMP set command to my server.  I can see the packet in wireshark, and I know that I'm getting the packet. Once I get this packet I need to decode it and do an operation (using a script).  I can't believe I am the first person that needs to do this, but have googled for hours and found no one else in this use case. I've seen utilities that allow me to use a get snmp, but as the set doesn't actually set anything on my server, there is no way to get it.  It doesn't seem traps are helpful as that seems to find the message, as its not labeled a trap.  Is there a way to convert the set to a trap once my server gets it, or is there a better method.  My server is windows, but if I have to create a linux VM to make this easier I'm all ears.  As of now I'm thinking powershell, but if there is an easy way in go, c#, etc I would totally do it.

I am attempting to get a SNMP SET to and use that as a trigger for running a script.

Comment: Is SNMP enabled on network?  Did you install any cmdlets?  Following article may be helpful : https://www.auvik.com/franklyit/blog/network-basics-what-is-snmp/

Comment: What is this tagged ***PowerShell***? This is not a PS code issue, but a how-do-it question. Anything you are trying to interact with must provide the interface/attribute/property to do so. If that tool/service/thing does not, then there's not much you can do programmatically with any language. So, your query is really asking for an opinion on how-do-i-it, which is not appropriate for SO as defined in the rules. [What did you search for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27c%23+snmp+set%27%27&t=h_&ia=web)?

Comment: Remember SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) --- [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You will have to explain further on "I have a something that is sending an SNMP set command to my server". If you don't have an SNMP engine (usually agent) running on this server, that SNMP SET packet should be dropped as desired. Use search engines to learn more about SNMP agents and you should figure out what you need next.

Comment: I don’t really. A message is sent using the SNMP protocol for set this MIB to value X. This is standard SNMP command. I’m not sending it, an application is. I just want to run a powershell script to run when the set command comes to my server. I would love for this to work like REST or a normal server-client but it doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

You are 100% correct in that you are not the first person to ask this question.  The answer depends on which SNMP agent you have deployed.  Many people have had success with [Net SNMP](https://www.net-snmp.org/) and if you want to invoke a shell script from the SNMP agent, [see this tutorial](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tut:Extending_snmpd_using_shell_scripts).  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using pythons pysnmp to build an agent that would recieve the set/get requests. I had to compile my own MIBs for the PDU I was emulating, but got the job done.  I also looked into Net SNMP, but I'm more familiar with python and found many helpful examples and good documentation.

I would like to flatten my use case, but at the moment I have two scripts, one that is the agent using pysnmp and one that will do a get request to see what the value is and set off a ssh script.  I wish I could hook into the snmp set function, like when the var is written, but for now I have working setup. If anyone wants me to post my code I can.

Copied a lot of code from the second example here:
https://pysnmp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html
Learned about MIB compiling and used the mbidump.py tool.  Looks like if you don't provide the proper file the old host server might be compromised and it downloads a file automatically...so be careful.